# Problem with batch write when updating data that no longer exist in Firestore database - iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In a scenario where the product is already in the cart and the user enters the credit card number and enters the OTP, this process could take a few seconds or even minutes, where anything could happen like the admin deleted that product. And if the payment is successful, a batch of functions will get triggered, functions like update the product's stock level, add order to user's purchase history, etc. I use batch write for this operation. However, when the product is no longer in the database, what it will do is that it re-creates the product containing a stock level field. Could you please recommend a way to prevent this error? is batch write right for this operation?

```
    // Update item stocklevel
        var newVar = String()
        var newIds = [String:Any]()

        for (key, value) in itemsDict {
            let newValue = value as! [String:Any]
            let newId = newValue[kITEMID] as! String
            newVar = newValue[kVARIATIONKEY] as! String
            let newQty = newValue[kQUANTITY] as! Int


            for i in 0..<self.allItems.count {
                let newVars = self.allItems[i].variations!
                let newKey = self.allItems[i].varKey!
                let filteredVars = newVars.filter({$0.key == String(newKey)})


                for (_, value) in filteredVars {
                     guard let resultNew = value as? [String:Any] else { return }
                     let stock = resultNew[kSTOCK] as! Int

                    let newStock = stock - newQty
                    let anyDict = [newVar:[kSTOCK:newStock]] as [String:Any]

                    updateStock = [newId: [kVARIATIONS:anyDict]] as [String:Any]

                    newIds.updateValue(updateStock, forKey: key)

                }
            }

        } 

    let batch = Firestore.firestore().batch()

    for (_, value) in newIds {

        let newValue = value as! [String:Any]

        for (k1, v1) in newValue {
            let newV1 = v1 as! [String:Any]

            // update stock level
            batch.setData(newV1, forDocument: FirebaseReference(.Items).document(k1), merge: true)
        }

    }

    // add to users purchase history
    batch.setData(purchaseHistory, forDocument: ref2!, merge: true)

    // add to all orders list
    batch.setData(newAllOrders, forDocument: ref3!, merge: true)


    if oneTimeUse {
        if let newVoucherId = voucherId {

           let withValues = [kCLAIMEDBY: [MUser.currentUser()!.objectId]]

           ref4 = FirebaseReference(.Voucher).document(newVoucherId)

           // update voucher
           batch.setData(withValues, forDocument: ref4!, merge:true)
       }
    }


    self.showLoadingIndicator()
    batch.commit { (err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("There's an error with your order, please try again \(err.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            print("successfully commited batch")

            self.finalProcess(transactionId, paymentOption) {

            }


        }

    }
```

Comment: There's a number of things we don't know about your code. For example `self.allItems`; is that ALL of the items in your database? Are you loading all firebase nodes into memory? At what point are you attempting to update the nodes? Right after the user enters their card number and pushes 'Go'? `newIds` appears to be an empty array but yet it's being updated here `newIds.updateValue(updateStock, forKey: key)`. Can you reduce the amount of code and clarify whats being asked? Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The products have different variation, this is the structure of the database. [Product 1: [Var A: dict, Var B: dict].  Products in the basket are stored in itemsDict [Item1: Product 1 Var A, item2: Product 1 Var B]. self.allItems is an array of Product object that are in the basket, self.allItems = [Product 1 Var A, Product 1 Var B] this is the datasource of my tableview. Stock level is only updated when the payment is successful and not when the time you click on the 'Go'. Thanks

Comment: Just thinking outside the box a bit... Maybe a different approach. Part of the power of Firebase is real time updates. Meaning that if something within Firebase changes, the app will be notified of that change. If a shopper adds 3 items to their cart, then perhaps adding an observer to those items would eliminate the issue. Your app will always know how many items are available and if the qty goes to 0 or is removed, you'd know that before attempting to update it. You could also leverage that to motivate the user to make the purchase *'Attention Shopper: There's only 3 widgets left!'*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend you to use [Transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions) for these operations you are making, and quoting the documentation

"A transaction consists of any number of get() operations followed by any number of write operations such as set(), update(), or delete(). In the case of a concurrent edit, Cloud Firestore runs the entire transaction again. For example, if a transaction reads documents and another client modifies any of those documents, Cloud Firestore retries the transaction. This feature ensures that the transaction runs on up-to-date and consistent data."

This would help you to prevent these scenarios where the product is not available in stock anymore and you can display/send a message to the user that was interested on this product.

Comment: Leaning on a transaction ensures that it either all completes or it fails, and I am not sure that's what's needed here because if there are 10 items and one fails the OP still wants to update the other 9.

Comment: Thanks chinoche. I've tried transactions and this doesn't solve the problem either. @Jay, the newIds contains the ids of the products that need to be updated, would it be too much if I will query the database first before updating?

Comment: @TSM you could query that collection inside the transaction just to make sure that your business rule is correct or not and then proceed to the update operation and prevent any concurrency errors (the stock was change by other users, for example)

Comment: Hi @chinoche, I tried the transaction again, I placed it inside the update-stocklevel for loop, removed the batch operation, and replaced it with transaction operation and it works. I still use batch for the rest of the operations. Thank you